# PHP - $_SERVER('PHP_SELF') error using XAMPP

Tags: php, server, xampp, superglobals

I am a Windows 7 user and I am creating a website on localhost:8080/ using XAMPP. I want to make a contact form using PHP for getting the data from the form(name, email, message) and sending them to my email. Here's what the form looks like in html **so far**:

```
<form class="contact-form" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" >
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name">
    <br><br>
    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="E-mail (required)" required>
    <br><br>
    <textarea name="message" placeholder="Type your message here..." rows="5" cols="30"></textarea>
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

I am using the following PHP script:

```
<body>
    <?php
        $emailValidation = "";
        if (filter_has_var(INPUT_POST, 'submit')) {
            $email = $_POST['email'];
            $name = $_POST['name'];
            $message = $_POST['message'];

            if (!empty($email) && !empty($name) && !empty($message)) {

            } else {

            }

            if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
              $emailValidation = "Invalid email format";
            }
        }
    ?>
.....stuff
</body>
```

When I submit the form the following error appears:
[image]

I have tried modifying the **httpd-vhosts.conf** file by adding the following lines:

```
<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/ColdBeatz-Site">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
    Order Deny,Allow
    Allow from all
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

... but the problem remains!

**NOTE:** If I use a file (eg. contact.php) on **action** attribute, it is working fine!

Comment: Your PHP code is not being executed. Is PHP installed properly on your WAMP server?

Comment: See: [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10600564/wamp-server-isnt-executing-php-code

Comment: I haven't installed any PHP, apparently XAMPP has PHP already installed. If it wasn't installed, the "contact.php" file wouldn't be executed as well(?)

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.

I just had to create a file called ".htaccess" at the same path with my html file and write the line: " **AddType application/x-httpd-php .htm .html** ".

Answer (score 0):

You should run the form code using server.
I think that you should not run the form code in HTML file.

Comment: "You should run the form code using server" — they are, they is why the screenshot shows `localhost` in the address bar.

Comment: Maybe you didn't set all the settings in the setting files such as config and index.php files. Please set all the config files correctly.